# В чём разница между сборкой и библиотекой?

Tags: c#, теория

Перечитываю о пространстве имён и сборке и что-то зацепился за эти слова.

> #### Пространства имен и сборки
>
> Директива `using` просто помещает элементы пространства имен в область видимости и освобождает вас от необходимости использования в именах кода полной классификации. Классы компилируются в сборки.
>
> Сборка представляет собой файл, для имени которого обычно используется расширение `.dll`, хотя, строго говоря, исполняемые программы в файлах с расширением `.exe` также являются сборками.
>
> В сборке может содержаться множество классов. Классы, включенные в библиотеку классов .NET Framework, например `System.Console`, предоставляются в сборках, устанавливаемых на ваш компьютер вместе с Visual Studio. Вы увидите, что библиотека классов .NET Framework содержит тысячи классов. Если бы все они содержались в одной сборке, она была бы слишком большой и сложной в сопровождении. (Если бы компании Microsoft понадобилось обновить всего лишь один метод в одном из классов, то ей пришлось бы распространить всю библиотеку классов среди всех разработчиков!)
>
> Поэтому библиотека классов .NET Framework разбита на целый ряд сборок, разделенных функциональными областями, к которым относятся содержащиеся в них классы.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы. Просто под библиотекой авторы в этом контексте книги подразумевают набор из нескольких dll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Сборка** - **это файл**, в который упакован код на языке `MSIL`, метаданные и данные ресурсов (текст, изображения и т.п.).

**Сборка без "входной точки запуска"**, т.е. без `static void Main(string[] args)` **называется** библиотекой классов или просто **библиотекой**, такому файлу компилятором назначается расширение файла `dll`. **Если** же **в сборке есть** класс имеющий эту **"входную точку запуска"**, то такая **сборка считается исполняемым файлом** и соотв. имеет расширение `exe`.

> В чём разница между сборкой и библиотекой?

Библиотека - это особый вид сборки или, если хотите, файла.

Приведенная вами цитата -- это яркий пример неудачного перевода на русский язык. Английское слово `assembly`, действительно можно перевести как `сборка`. Однако, в абзац про устройство пространства имен .Net Framework русское слово сборка вносит некоторую двусмысленность из-за своего дополнительного смысла, которого нет в английском слове `assembly`.

Ну, вы сильно не пугайтесь. Далее вы ещё встретите, например, такое слово как **Поток**, которым переводятся сразу два разных английских слова `Stream` и `Thread`, которые конечно обозначают совершенно два разных понятия.